# beat somebody to 'a' pulp ( why is pulp countable here?)

Tags: articles, indefinite-article, uncountable-nouns, countable-nouns

I just stumbled over this phrase and I'd like to know why the rule of countable/uncountable nouns doesn't seem to apply here? Pulp is not a countable unit.

Comment: "Pulp" is not a count noun; it's a singular non-count noun. A few non-count singular nouns like "pulp" can occur with the determiner "a": "A **number** of people complained"; "I don't have a great **deal** of time"; "Ed has a good **knowledge** of Latin". In those examples, "knowledge" is a clear non-count noun while "number" and "deal" are being used in their quantificational non-count sense.

Comment: @BillJ  This doesn't add up to me. If something is singular and uncountable how should I know which noun requires an article then? There is no consistency at all. There are more exceptions to rules than rules itself.

Comment: The 'singular' component of the term 'singular non-count noun' simply indicates that the noun takes singular verb agreement, not because it acts like a singular count noun by taking the article _a_. Items like "crockery", "footwear", "furniture" etc. are all non-count singular nouns; they take singular verbs, but they can't take _a_. There are also 'plural non-count nouns' like "clothes", "scissors", "vermin" etc. which take plural verbs. In general, the article _a_ selects a count singular noun. There are only a very small number of exceptions, as I mentioned, so no big problem.

Comment: *Pulp*, despite what Cambridge dictionary says, is not used as a count noun. The idea of *a pulp* is the same as *a coffee*, as in *a type of pulp/coffee*.

Answer (score 1):

The Cambridge Dictionary indicates that [*pulp*](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/pulp) can be treated as either a singular or uncountable [S or U] noun, so using the indefinite article in the phrase "beat somebody to a pulp" is not out of the ordinary, even if the idiom is something of a fixed expression.

> **pulp** noun [S or U]
>
> a soft, wet mass:
>
> - Mash the bananas to a pulp and then mix in the yogurt.

Cambridge Dictionary

Comment: I thought an uncountable noun doesn't get an article, neither definite nor indefinite.

Comment: @Chris I trust the Cambridge in this matter. Many nouns take only a singular form, for example, *frenzy*: "She got into a frenzy." (Although the Camdridge says that [*frenzy*](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/frenzy) is both countable and uncountable. One frenzy, two frenzies. Perhaps.)

Answer (score 0):

Mick's answer cites that pulp can be treated as either singular or uncountable.  I'll expand on a context for why that makes sense.

Even a non-count noun can be used in a countable way if you apply it to multiple different things.  Each thing is not in countable units, but you have multiple different things, so if you refer to the things, those are countable.

Pulp isn't countable, but you can have different kinds of pulp.  If you mash a banana, you get banana pulp.  If you beat a person, you get person pulp.  You can't beat a person into banana pulp.  All kinds of pulp aren't the same thing.  So "**a** pulp" has the meaning of "a kind of pulp", an example of one of many kinds of pulp.  In that sense, the "a" is appropriate.

Think of a situation where two people encounter a soft, wet mass of unknown material.  One asks the other what it is.  The other might say, "Well, it's **a** pulp of some kind."  He wouldn't say, "It's pulp" because that might describe it's state but not what substance it is.